# how to import and export date time format data from json to nosql(firestore)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Input:

Created_At:Monday, 29 April 2019 15:07:59 GMT+05:30

Updated_At:Monday, 29 April 2019 15:07:59 GMT+05:30

I Tried  export data (Json Format)from firestore using (firestore-export-import)npm but i get an output on

```
        "Updated_At": {
            "_seconds": 1556530679,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        },
        "Created_At": {
            "_seconds": 1556530679,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        }
```

From

Created_At:Monday, 29 April 2019 15:07:59 GMT+05:30

Updated_At:Monday, 29 April 2019 15:07:59 GMT+05:30

is there any alternate method how to get  timestamp format(Monday, 29 April 2019 15:07:59 GMT+05:30)
This is my Import export code..

export.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var firestoreService = require('firestore-export-import');
var databaseURL = 'https://sample.firebaseio.com';
var serviceAccount = require('../sample.json'); // Initiate Firebase App
firestoreService.initializeApp(serviceAccount, databaseURL);
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
// Start exporting your data
firestoreService
    .backup('sample') //collection ,sub collection
    .then(data => {
fs.writeFile("sample.json", JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
if (err) {
console.log("error:", err.message);
res.json({
returncode: 201,
message: err.message
          })
        } else {
console.log("Data Exported Sucessfully");
res.json({
returncode: 200,
message: "Data Exported Sucessfully"
          })
        }
      });
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

**import.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const firestoreService = require("firestore-export-import");
var databaseURL = "https://sample.firebaseio.com";
var serviceAccount = require("../sample.json"); // Initiate Firebase App
firestoreService.initializeApp(serviceAccount, databaseURL);
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
firestoreService
    .restore("./sample.json") //json file
    .then(async function () {
console.log("Data Imported Successfully");
return res.json({
returncode: 200,
message: "Data Imported Successfully"
      });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
return res.json({
returncode: 201,
message: err.message
      });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.Timestampcreation = functions.region('Your-Region')
.firestore.document('CollectionName/{DocumentID}') //InitiateCollectionName and DocumentIdName
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
const DocId = context.params.Id;
const data = snap.data();
console.log(snap.data());
console.log(data.Created_At); //data.fieldname1
console.log(data.Updated_At); //data.fieldname2
const createddate = new admin.firestore.Timestamp(data.Created_At._seconds, data.Created_At._nanoseconds) //As Timestamp is under firebase.firestore namespace
const updateddate = new admin.firestore.Timestamp(data.Updated_At._seconds, data.Updated_At._nanoseconds)
console.log(createddate);
console.log(updateddate);
const TimestampRef = admin.firestore().collection(CollectionName).doc(DocId);
return TimestampRef.update({
Created_At: createddate,
Updated_At: updateddate
});
});
```

Comment: Before import, this cloudfunction modify and deployed based for your project

Answer (score 0):

when you export your date from firestore you will always receive [firebase. firestore. Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).

which has two properties **seconds** and **nanoseconds**. so it's normal that you receive an output like the one you posted:

```
"Updated_At": {
    "_seconds": 1556530679,
    "_nanoseconds": 0
},
"Created_At": {
    "_seconds": 1556530679,
    "_nanoseconds": 0
}
```

to convert it to javascript Date :

1- use **[toDate method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#to-date)** which return Date object in millisecond.

2- after that using normal javascript methods convert the Date (in milliseconds) to an actual date like in:

```
const date = new Date(dateInMilliseconds);
```

you will get a result like:

Fri Mar 20 2020 13:33:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Comment: I am not able to understand please explain with another example @Methkal Khalawi

Comment: hey @VijayRahul , I updated my answer. Please accept it if it solves your issue.